# Optimisation of float vector elements' comparison

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, floating-point, comparison

Profiling the following code (updated):

```
struct myStruct {
    float a;
    float b;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<myStruct> myVector;
    float tmp,tmp2,absVal;

    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        tmp2 = (i%10)/100.f;

        for(myStruct &s : boost::adaptors::reverse(myVector))
        {
            tmp = s.a;
            absVal = fabs(tmp-tmp2);

            if(absVal<0.0001f)
            {
                s.b = 1.5f;
            }
        }

        myStruct s;
        s.a = tmp2;
        myVector.push_back(s);

    }
}
```

I can see, that 50% of time it spends on comparison absVal<0.0001.
Can I reduce time spent on this comparison?

Code was compiled with -O2 flag, clang-602.0.53. Profiling was done using Apple's Instruments with Time Profiler.

Comment: Maybe we are getting different random numbers or some such, but in my build (using clang-3.7 as of about two weeks ago), most of the time is accounted for in the `tmpAbs = fabs(tmp-i);` and the loop iteration [although I rewrite it using `rbegin` and `rend` as I can't be bothered to figure out how to use boost in this case - I doubt that makes much difference - I expect that's what the `boost::adaptor::reverse` does anyway] - using -O3 takes about 1s off the time...

Comment: Having had another look at the logic, the first if should never be entered... [I just proved that by adding `assert(0)` at the end of the loop - and the compiler made the whole thing faster by removing some code in the loop - not sure what, don't really care]

Comment: In other words, your tool that show how much time you spend where is not working correctly.

Comment: Thank you @MatsPetersson. The code above is just an example, real application is much more complex and both if's can be entered. I was using Apple's Instruments with Time Profiler - which tool do you use, so I can compare results with the same one?

Comment: I use linux's `perf` - I have a feeling that (or something similar) is what is "under neath" the Time Profiler in Apple's product. I expect that it's more a case of "what the debug information says" than the tool confusing which instruction takes time. Unfortunately, if your code doesn't ACTUALLY reflect the real application, making suggestions based on SOME OTHER code is kind of pointless.

Comment: After your comment I checked it once again in the "real" code and actually I was wrong in previous reply - it never enters this if. Realising this obviously helps to optimise the algorithm much more than focusing on floats comparison or vector's elements access. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask optimization questions here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/
stackoverflow is for finding bugs not optimizations!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most obvious improvements would be to compare floats to floats, and doubles to doubles. `0.001` is a `double`, `0.001f` is a float.

This is such an obvious improvement that the compiler might have made it silently for you. But the profiling results suggest it didn't.

You do have similar issues all over the place. `/ (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/2.))` in particular looks bad: casting of RAND_MAX to double, then dividing by 2.0 and casting the result back to float, floating-point division, and that all with a constant.

Alternatively:

```
static const float scale = 2.f/RAND_MAX;
(float i=0.f;i<1000.f;i+=0.01f)
{
  // ...
  s.b = rand() * scale;
```

Comment: @user2923525: Then the compiler already converted the values at compile time.